# How to get total numbers of day in current week in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need help on how to do total numbers in each day within a current week. 
This is the sample result:
[image]

---

I can do the **total current day** and **total current week**, but still don't know how to do by day by day in a current week. This is my code on it.

```
drop procedure if exists GETTotalCallsToday;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GETTotalCallsToday(IN account_NO int(11))
BEGIN
    Select count(*) FROM logfile 
        WHERE DATE(Start_Call_Time) = CURDATE() 
        AND AccountNO = account_NO;
END //
DELIMITER ;
-- Example: CALL GETTotalCallsToday(1);

-- ---------------------------------------------------------

drop procedure if exists GETTotalCallsThisWeek;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GETTotalCallsThisWeek(IN account_NO int(11))
BEGIN
     Select count(*) FROM logfile 
        WHERE YEARWEEK(Start_Call_Time, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
        AND AccountNO = account_NO;
END //
DELIMITER ;
-- Example: CALL GETTotalCallsThisWeek(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the date:

```
Select 
  DATE(Start_Call_Time) as theday,
  count(*) as thecount
FROM logfile 
WHERE 
  Start_call_time > date_sub( curdate(), interval 7 day)
  AccountNO = account_NO
GROUP BY
  DATE(Start_Call_Time)
```

This will produce two columns of 7 rows which is the data you're asking for but not the form you're asking for. To get it into a row of 7 columns we have to pivot it. There are a couple of ways we can do this, and this way is a good one because it works in various situations in different databases:

```
Select 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(Start_Call_Time), CURDATE() = 6 THEN 1 END) as six,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(Start_Call_Time), CURDATE() = 5 THEN 1 END) as five,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(Start_Call_Time), CURDATE() = 4 THEN 1 END) as four,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(Start_Call_Time), CURDATE() = 3 THEN 1 END) as three,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(Start_Call_Time), CURDATE() = 2 THEN 1 END) as two,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(Start_Call_Time), CURDATE() = 1 THEN 1 END) as one,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(Start_Call_Time), CURDATE() = 0 THEN 1 END) as zero,
  count(*) as total
FROM logfile 
WHERE 
  Start_call_time > date_sub( curdate(), interval 7 day)
  AccountNO = account_NO
```

For each date column this uses a case when to ask whether the difference between date of the call versus the current date is a particular number of days - essentially "was the call tiday, yesterday, 2 etc days ago?" Yes - return a 1 else return a null. Count will count one every time any non null value is returned. This is how the calls are allocated to be counted in a particular column. If you strip out the count operations it makes more sense. Here's what you see for a two calls today and one yesterday, without the counts:

```
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL
```

The last column being for datediff zero = today. When counted they will collapse to a single row:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2
```

Do not try and call your column headers a date ; that's a job for the front end displaying this data. Database data should have a fixed number of columns with fixed names, if the zero column is showing Monday data, the six column is data from last tuesday

Realistically and for simplicity of your code you should be using the first query and let the front end transpose the data. If you're dead set on the dB doing it, call your columns after the days of the week and always run your report on a certain day

Comment: thanks I lot on this, because of this I've got an idea.